# How to define route (source location to destination) in react-native Map

Tags: react-native

How to define the route between source and destination in google map.

I have used google map library `react-native-maps`.

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/52

Comment: Also how can i create dynamic marker ?

Comment: check the marker examples https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/tree/master/example/examples